# Mayavi/IPython shell not expected behavior

Tags: python, command-line, ipython, mayavi

I am trying to learn tips and tricks for MAYAVI, [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html). For instance, I am trying to do the texture things in paragraph [texture mapping actors](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#texture-mapping-actors). This is some command line code, and I thought I could prompt this directly in IPython (I am with Win 7).

This is not working with IPython, with IPython (sh) neither.

[image: Not working with IPython, what's wrong?]

BTW, what is difference between the different command line option in python(x,y): IPython, IPython Qt, IPython pythonxy and Python interpreter ?

How to try this code sample? Is it possible with windows or should I turn it into a script ?

Also, I am trying to do [this](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/advanced_scripting.html#advanced-scripting-with-mayavi), paragraph Object-Oriented construction of a visualization. Tutorial mentions that

> As with all Mayavi code, you need to have the GUI mainloop running to
>   have the visualization go live. Typing this code in ipython -wthread
>   (or ipython –gui=wx in the recent versions) will do this for you.

None of both solutions is working. [Some web things mention](http://mindseye.no/) that now `--pylab=qt` should be used instead, which is also not working. BTW, what is implied by 'have visualization go live'? that you see things move right after typing some command? This is in the scipting page of doc: I thought I would simply as I always do have a script, compile it, and see result at run time. Some enlightnings on this topic?

Thanks and regards.

###  EDIT: I solved part of it with doc

> If you are using the Enthought Python Distribution, or the latest
>   Python(x,y) distribution, the Pylab menu entry will start ipython with
>   the right switch. In older release of Python(x,y) you need to start
>   “Interactive Console (wxPython)”.

But I am interested in tips regarding all other sections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run command line things from IPython, start the line with `!`. Don't include the `$`, that's the standard shell prompt on Unix (like the `>` in the Windows command prompt).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. however, command `!--pylab=qt`still not working. what is the syntax? why the `--` in this command? :  )

Comment: That's an option for when you're starting IPython itself: you would run `ipython --pylab=qt` from a command line. The 'pylab' menu entry should do the same thing.